# Array indexing using while loop and json encodeing not working in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

This code when run on our localhost works:

```
if($result){
     if($tmp=$result->num_rows){
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $myArray[]  = $row;
         }
       echo json_encode($myArray[0]);
     }
}
```

But, when it is run on the server (Godaddy Hosting) it reutrns a null value.

Comment: Same DB connection? Whats `$result->num_rows`?

Comment: Are you use $tmp variable save $result->num_rows() output or compare with them.

Comment: Is your live DB similar to local DB in terms of the structure and data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any results in your database. If yes, then check if you have any non-ASCII caracters which makes your json_encode returning false, or encode them with [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $myArray[]  = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
```

You can also use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to help you debbuging.